# $\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty } \frac{2^n + 8^n}{10^n} = ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, exponential-sum

im looking for hints on how to do: $\sum\limits_{n=4}^{n=  \infty } 
\frac{2^n + 8^n}{10^n}  = ?$

I thought this may have had something to do with geometric series but nothing obvious comes up

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just write it as a sum of two geometric  series?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: you can write 
$\sum\limits_{n=4}^{n=  \infty } 
\frac{2^n + 8^n}{10^n}  = 
\sum\limits_{n=4}^{n=  \infty } 
\frac{2^n }{10^n}  + 
\sum\limits_{n=4}^{n=  \infty } 
\frac{8^n }{10^n} 
$
because the two series on the right hand side converge.
And then you have two geometric series, which you can probably solve.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty } \frac{2^n + 8^n}{10^n} \\ = \sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty }\left( \frac{1}{5^n}+\frac{4^n}{5^n}\right)\\=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{5}}-1-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{25}-\frac{1}{125}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{5}}-1-\frac{4}{5}-\frac{16}{25}-\frac{64}{125}\\=0.002+2.048\\=2.05$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty} 
\frac{2^n + 8^n}{10^n}  &= \sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty } 
\frac{2^n}{10^n}+\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty } 
\frac{8^n}{10^n} \\  &=\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty } 
\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n+\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty } 
 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n \\  &=-1-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{25}-\frac{1}{125}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty } 
\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n-1-\frac{4}{5}-\frac{16}{25}-\frac{64}{125}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty } 
 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n \\  &=-1-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{25}-\frac{1}{125}-1-\frac{4}{5}-\frac{16}{25}-\frac{64}{125}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{5}}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{5}} \\  &= -3-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{17}{25}-\frac{65}{125}+\frac{5}{4}+5 = 2.05 \end{align*}